# Computing column in dataframe based on nearest value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `coarse` and `fine`. `fine` contains 3 columns `start_time, end_time, start_price, end_price`. `coarse` contains `start_time, end_time`. Note that all the times are pandas timestamp objects, e.g., `2016-12-12 01:03:13.15231+00:00`

For `coarse` I need to add 2 additional columns `start_price, end_price`, where `coarse.start_price` is the the `fine.start_price` that has a `fine.start_time` closest to `coarse.start_time`, and analogously so for `end_price`.

Here's an example for clarity:

```
coarse:

start_time                              end_time
2016-12-12 01:00:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 02:00:00.000+00:00
2016-12-12 02:00:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 03:00:00.000+00:00
2016-12-12 03:00:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 03:30:00.000+00:00
```

```
fine:

start_time                              end_time                         start_price 
2016-12-12 00:59:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 01:12:00.000+00:00    2.3
2016-12-12 01:12:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 01:15:00.000+00:00    4.5
2016-12-12 01:15:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 01:45:00.000+00:00    5.7
2016-12-12 01:45:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 01:55:00.000+00:00    8.8
2016-12-12 01:55:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 02:15:00.000+00:00    9.9
2016-12-12 02:15:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 02:16:00.000+00:00    11.2
2016-12-12 02:16:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 02:31:00.000+00:00    13.5
2016-12-12 02:31:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 02:45:00.000+00:00    14.8
2016-12-12 02:45:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 02:59:00.000+00:00    15.9
2016-12-12 02:59:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 03:31:00.000+00:00    16.0
```

So the result should be

```
coarse:
 
start_time                              end_time                         start_price
2016-12-12 01:00:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 02:00:00.000+00:00    2.3
2016-12-12 02:00:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 03:00:00.000+00:00    9.9
2016-12-12 03:00:00.000+00:00           2016-12-12 03:30:00.000+00:00    16.0
```

(I skipped `end_price` because it's the same logic). I am wondering what is the easiest way to do this?

Additionally, rather than using the nearest neighbor, I may consider interpolating the price instead based on the times. Is there an easy way to do this as well?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) which is perfect for joining on times that don't match exactly.  There is a direction parameter which you can adjust to cause the match to go the direction you want.

```
import pandas as pd

coarse = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': ['2016-12-12 01:00:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:00:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 03:00:00.000+00:00'], 'end_time': ['2016-12-12 02:00:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 03:00:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 03:30:00.000+00:00']} )

fine = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': ['2016-12-12 00:59:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 01:12:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 01:15:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 01:45:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 01:55:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:15:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:16:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:31:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:45:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:59:00.000+00:00'], 'end_time': ['2016-12-12 01:12:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 01:15:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 01:45:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 01:55:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:15:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:16:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:31:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:45:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 02:59:00.000+00:00', '2016-12-12 03:31:00.000+00:00'], 'start_price': [2.3, 4.5, 5.7, 8.8, 9.9, 11.2, 13.5, 14.8, 15.9, 16.0]})

coarse['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(coarse['start_time'])
fine['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(fine['start_time'])
coarse['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(coarse['end_time'])
fine['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(fine['end_time'])


coarse = pd.merge_asof(coarse, fine[['start_time','start_price']],
                       on='start_time',
                       direction='nearest')

coarse = pd.merge_asof(coarse,
                       fine[['end_time','start_price']].rename(columns={'start_price':'end_price'}),
                       on='end_time',
                       direction='nearest')
```

Output

```
                 start_time                  end_time  start_price  end_price
0 2016-12-12 01:00:00+00:00 2016-12-12 02:00:00+00:00          2.3        8.8
1 2016-12-12 02:00:00+00:00 2016-12-12 03:00:00+00:00          9.9       15.9
2 2016-12-12 03:00:00+00:00 2016-12-12 03:30:00+00:00         16.0       16.0
```

Comment: ah this is perfect. is it possible to join based on an interpolation of the 2 nearest times using this method?

Comment: Maybe join twice, once in each direction and groupby/average the results or something